# Check variable is public php

Tags: php, variables

I want to check if a local variable in a class is public or private.
The reason is to create a function like this:

```
function ToArray() {
  $arr = array();
  foreach($this as $key => $val) {
    $arr[$key] = $val;
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

This function also return private fields, and I don't want that. How can I get only public variables here?

Comment: you cannot do `foreach($this...)`

Comment: Yes, I can, and I do. Foreach on an object loops through the properties in the object. Just try it by yourself. Foreach on $this also returns private and protected properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php),

```
$foo = new Foo();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print $prop->getName() . "\n";
}

var_dump($props);
```

Comment: $key = $prop->getName();
$value = $this->$key;

Thank you.

Comment: When you copy text from another source, **you must link back to the original source,** otherwise it looks like plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all public attributes call `get_object_vars()`.

(Hint: calling it by the object itself will return all attributes.)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to follow some naming convention with your private variables (like i prepend them with `_`)

Then just return those variables that do **not** have `_` in the beginning of their key.

Comment: There are keywords in the language so that we don't need conventions like this.  It's nothing more than [hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for access instead of types (and it's generally accepted that hungarian notation is not needed in modern languages, so don't even bother)...

Comment: This is not generally recommended: Underscores are a stylistic choice, rather than enforced by the language, and aren't a bulletproof method to define or check variable scope.